# Linux how can i learn it? administration/user

Tags: linux

I would like to get help. Soo one day i got this book: http://linuxcommand.org/images/51vgLTkNsIL._SL500_AA300_.jpg And i have learned some "basic of terminal + linux". I have read the full book, but i want more, u guys now, i wanna be better and better... But i got no idea what books can i read, what sities should i read, at what turtionals video i should look. I just want learn more linux as typical user/administration (linux is soo fun :P) I don"t want learn linux as programmer.

I just search a places to learn more linux, like i said, i got only a linux basic from this book: http://linuxcommand.org/images/51vgLTkNsIL._SL500_AA300_.jpg But i would like to learn more, any ideas at what should i look?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely agree with Optavius, mucking around in the trenches is the only way to get dirty ;)

I would like to add that, given the wide variety of linux distributions available, another way to learn more is to start out with two or three different ones.  For example, get things running on a Debian derivative (e.g. Ubuntu), and start comparing the subtle differences with say a RedHat derivative (e.g. Fedora).

For example, you would learn a good deal just by comparing the differences of installing / managing packages with `apt-get` on Ubuntu, and `yum` on Fedora.  With `apt-get`, if you want to search for a package you would have to do `apt-cache search <package_name>`, and when you find it then you would do `apt-get install <package_name>`.  Whereas with `yum`, you would just do `yum search <package_name>` and `yum install <package_name>`.

Personally, if you want to become *very* experienced with system administration, I strongly recommend installing Fedora.  The reason is because it is very forward, and constantly updating and evolving.  This comes at a significant price.  Yes, you have all of those shiny new tools that many other distributions would have to install from source.  But this also makes it very unstable, and will break frequently.  A kernel update may require you to go in and fix things with `dracut` for no apparent reason!

The other side of the coin is that Ubuntu has an extremely vast user-base, and when you end up having a problem it is much more likely that you will find a current solution for Ubuntu.

The bottom line: play around and have some fun!!!  Maybe setup RAID or create some shared partitions.  Say you had Windows and Linux, and wanted to have all of your music on one separate partition that both could access.  Then make an exFAT partition for both to share, and learn how to auto-mount this in Linux (how depends on the distribution).

If you really, really, REALLLLLY want to learn about linux from the ground up, there's a solution for that too: cook your own distribution!  You've demonstrated you aren't opposed to reading a book or two, [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) may be exactly what you are looking for.  This is not for the faint-hearted, though...

I hope one of those thoughts sparks something of interest to you!!!

Comment: Hi, thx u alot for tips and help :-} I play evryday with my Linux (no homo :P) . I have already learned package - on deb and rpm, i also learned creating users/groups, chmod, chown (and others things) + sudoers  + grub edit . And More More :P

Comment: haaahaha cool beans :)  I'll present a challenge for you then.  Premise: you have a linux box you want access to, but no user account.  What you can use: usb linux (note this requires a full install, not a virtual machine).  WITHOUT using `chroot`, find a way to give yourself an account.  Don't be crazy -- don't do it at work or school or wherever the law may disallow. Hint1: do some reading on /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow. Hint2: those aren't the only two you need to change. Hint3: this is called `salting`, and you will need the same distribution on the USB as the one you are hacking

Comment: Interesing :P when i will get time, i gonna try it :P i gonna learn alot from this challenge thx u :-}  Soo hmm, hmm interesing but, idk if i understand all good: Soo i got a linux with no users(or idk the passwords,usernames etc for them), and i  need get a account, right? Soo i just need to hack something, and read password?

Comment: Tehe! You have a linux box that has say 2 users, only one of whom has admin privileges. You want to add yourself as a user on this box, but they went on vacation and you can't wait any longer. The first  step is to find a way to become that user by changing their password. This is where /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow come in. You will need to look at /etc/group to see who has admin privileges and who does not.  Now that you can log in as admin, you can easily become root and add a new user.  Make sure to change their password back so they don't know what happened! Using `chroot` is boring ;)

Comment: P.S. This challenge should demonstrate why if you actually want any security, you absolutely must encrypt your hard drive.  Otherwise anybody who has physical access to your machine can make all sorts of changes without your permission.  After completing this, you can do it with `chroot` to see how the regular folks do it ;)

Comment: HMM :p  don"t say anything more ;P Now i understand all, and i gonna try it, i think it won"t be hard for me, also  i have never tested linux security, to be honest - when i got something important i encrypt it with truecrypt + if i would get something special, i just encypt whole disk + files. Still Linux > Windows, it"s like 100x more secure.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you install Linux instead and play around with it instead of reading about it. But it really depends really what you intend to achieve with using Linux.

Comment: Hi, i got linux on virtual machine/desktop. It"s not like i just read book (it would be boring), i also test all by myself, And i use Linux :-}

Comment: @Doniu I haven't used virtual machine much but if using a separate box (computer) for Linux, I find it useful for it to be a spare one where I can experiment without worrying about messing something up.